# How to do do server validation the correct way for a form in php?

Tags: php, wordpress, validation

I want to do some validation on the post data sent from a form before I send the data to an API. Could I just have the logic for the validation above the the place where I spit out the markup for the form? Is this bad practice to have it all in the same file? I want the user to stay on the page where the form is so I don't know how to do it in another way.

It's a WordPress project if it matters at all.

Comment: "It's a WordPress project if it matters at all." yes it matters quite a lot as wordress will have its own built-in functions to do this

Comment: No, it's not bad practice to include the markup in a single file - a basic check for if one of the required `$_POST` variables isset, toggling validation or form output, is pretty standard. However, coding forms and validation for WP is not always the best way - depending on your situation, a plugin such as Gravity Forms may provide a better experience for site admins, and it has built-in validation of many kinds.

Comment: @rtfm What kind of functions does wordpress have for this? I was just thinking of using the $_POST variable and do checks on that

Answer (score 0):

> It's a WordPress project if it matters at all.

Sure! It's good info to know because:

1. You'll likely want to "hook" into an action somewhere in WP's execution and do your validation.
2. There won't be a problem retrieving your submitted form's variables from the `$_POST` superglobal.

This is a WordPress specific anti-pattern, but I like to encapsulate my form rendering inside of a function, so it's easy to use as [shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) or widget, later.

Rendering the form as a shortcode will automagically drop your function into a workable stage of WordPress's execution, so that's the example I'll give, below:

```
// functions.php
function renderMyForm()
{
    $html        = '';
    $isSubmitted = false;
    $submitParam = 'something-specific-to-our-form';

    if ('POST' === $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']
        && key_exists($submitParam, $_POST)
        && !empty($_POST[$submitParam])
    ) {
        // A form was submitted, *and* it was our form.

        $formIsValid = false;

        // Do your validation checks here

        if (true === $formIsValid) {
            // Do the API stuff you mentioned in the Q
            $html = '<p>Thanks for submitting a valid form!</p>';
        } else {
            // Handle an invalid form. (Re-render your inputs with the submitted info) 
            $html = 'invalid data and any validation messages that the user should see.';
        }
    } else {
        // The form was not submitted. Regular `GET` request of a page it's embedded on.
        $html = 'your form\'s html here...';
    }

    return $html;
}
```

Then you could put `renderMyForm()` into a template, or do something like

```
add_shortcode('my-form', 'renderMyForm');
```

Which could be rendered by adding `[my-form]` into a page or post's content.

This is how Gravity Forms does it, as well as Contact Form 7 and likely a slew of others. It's not necessarily pretty or elegant, but it's The WordPress Way™, in some sense.